# Choosing integers from Qstring

Tags: qt, integer, qstring

I have saved date in QString "2013-12-01" and I need to convert it to three integers "yyyy", "mm" and "dd" for next operations.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: str.split('-') gives you an array of three strings.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to construct a QDate, you can use [QDate::fromString](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qdate.html#fromString) (with the YYYY-MM-DD format) or if you want just the integer values you can use what *Guid* already mentioned (QString::split)

Comment: Yes, i want QDate.
Thank you very much ;-)